# Is there a specific date for the Lensman series?

Tags: lensman-series

The first novel in the *Lensman* series, *Triplanetary*, begins at the creation of our solar system about 2,000,000,000 years ago - which is now believed to have actually been about 4,600,000,000 years ago - and includes an atomic war during the 20th century.  The main section of the novel occurs hundreds of years after the atomic war and thus probably before 3000 AD, as does the sequel *First Lensman*.

The novels *Galactic Patrol*, *Grey Lensman*, and *Second Stage Lensman* happen centuries or millennia later, and *The Children of the Lens* happens a generation after them.

I doubt there is any more precise date than that for the adventures of Kimball Kinneson.

But doe anyone have any reason or evidence for a more precise dating of the main *Lensman* series?